# using sprite for multiple bodies

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d

In my game I have a block sprite. With this sprite I've made a blockbody so that my character can't walk through it.

```
cocos2d::CCSprite* block = cocos2d::CCSprite::create("Block.png");
block->setPosition(ccp(5,20));
this->addChild(block);

b2BodyDef blockbodydef;
blockbodydef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
blockbodydef.position.Set(5/PTM_RATIO,20/PTM_RATIO);
blockbodydef.userData = block;
b2Body *blockbody = world->CreateBody(&blockbodydef);
b2PolygonShape blockPoly;
blockPoly.SetAsBox(37.5/PTM_RATIO , 37.5 / PTM_RATIO);
b2FixtureDef blockshapedef;
blockshapedef.shape = &blockPoly;
blockshapedef.density = 2.0f;
blockshapedef.friction = 0.2f;
blockshapedef.restitution = 0.8f;
blockbody->CreateFixture(&blockshapedef);
```

However, I want to have multiple of these blocks. Is there a way to like change the position of the bodydef and sprite without the original sprite disappearing or do I have to create a different sprite for each block?

Comment: You have to use multiple sprite for each block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another sprite for another block. Textures are cached inside cocos2dx, so it will be loaded from file only once.